# Was (is?) pre-marital sex illegal anywhere in the United States?

Tags: united-states, legal-history, marriage, history

I read this summary of [laws banning adultery](http://www.womansday.com/relationships/dating-marriage/a50994/adultery-laws/) in the United States.

Now, the wording of some of these laws made me wonder if any of them are remnants from a time when pre-marital sex (not just adultery) was banned. For example, maybe the pre-marital parts were removed, and the adultery parts were retained. Or maybe they are just interpreted differently now.

I certainly know that it was once illegal in [certain European countries.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leierm%C3%A5l)

Has pre-marital sex ever been illegal anywhere in the United States?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The legal term for premarital sex, as a crime, is **fornication**.  I found a paper that gives an extensive and well-referenced history and analysis of such laws:

> Sweeny, JoAnne.  Undead Statutes: The Rise, Fall and Continuing Uses of Adultery and Fornication Criminal Laws.  *Loyola University Chicago Law Journal* **46** (2014), 127–173.  http://www.luc.edu/media/lucedu/law/students/publications/llj/pdfs/vol46/Sweeny.pdf

Sweeny finds that many states (or even most) had such laws.  As of 2014, six states still do: Idaho, Utah, North Dakota, Illinois, Mississippi and South Carolina (see map on page 156 of the above paper).  However, they are likely unconstitutional under [*Lawrence v. Texas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_v._Texas).  Virginia and North Carolina also have laws that have already been found unconstitutional, but have not been repealed.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**

As recently as 6 February 2014 for sure and possibly right up until today in Virginia - http://www.nbcnews.com/news/crime-courts/virginia-bill-decriminalize-sex-outside-marriage-stalls-n23516. According to the article, there were 12 convictions in 2013, all as part of plea-bargains from more serious charges.

Comment: Certainly interesting.